# Not able to capture packet on tethering interface

Tags: android, networking, wireshark, tethering

I am browsing internet from my window 7 PC using android phone usb tethering feature.
I run the wireshark tool to capture packet over tethered interface .I selected all interface options using menu capture -> option-->capture on call interface
When I do ipconfig /all ,I see rndis interface with ipv4 address.

But the problem is I am not able to see any packets in the wireshark.
alternatively I also downloaded tcpdump for window
and the command
tcpdump -i any is not working throwing message "Error opening adapter"

I need the way to capture packets sent and received over tethered interface in PC.
Thanks